# Dynamic handling of Fragment

Tags: android-fragments

I am new on Android and recently I've been learning fragment.
I created a fragment with XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rlayout"
tools:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="13dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

java class for fragment:

```
public class fragmentclass extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout,container,false);
}
```

}

My main XML file contains a FrameLayout(with layout height 400dp) for fragment, inside a LinearLayout. My MainActivity java class is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentframe,new fragmentclass()).commit();
}
}
```

What troubled me is: when the app runs,only the button is displayed in the fragment portion.Shouldn't the parent layout of this button(the RelativeLayout in fragment's xml file) be displyed as well?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you see and what you should see,
but I'm also using fragments in one of my projects and used this guys tutorial 
to get started. Just pause and play as needed. Hope it helps.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ju837bQOBfg

Comment: What I want to see is: a fragment of blue colored layout(the layout in xml file for fragment) containing a button.   what I see is a button with white background all over the screen.